# Why do we approximate the joint in ELBO if we already have access to it?

Tags: machine-learning, variational-inference

I realized in variational inference, our goal is to approximate $p(z|x)$ with $q(z)$. So we minimize $KL(q(z) || p(z|x)) = \mathbb{E}_{z \sim q} log\frac{q(z)}{p(z|x)}$. We then manipulate, through some simple steps, to arrive at:

$$ = \mathbb{E}_{z \sim q} \left[ log \frac{q(z)}{p(z,x)}\right] + logp(x)$$

and then the objective becomes optimizing $q$ such that it is close to the joint... but don't we already have access to the full functional form of the joint? What's the point of approximating the joint if we already have access to it?

TLDR We want to minimize $KL(q(z) || p(z|x)) = \mathbb{E}_{z \sim q} log\frac{q(z)}{p(z|x)}$ but we don't have access to the posterior so we can't. We then decide to minimize $KL(q(z) || p(z,x)) = \mathbb{E}_{z \sim q} log\frac{q(z)}{p(z,x)}$ since we have access to the joint. My question, is why even approximate if we already have the joint?

Comment: Which of the expressions that you write down is supposed to be the full functional form of the joint probability?

Comment: I believe we have access to the full functional form of the joint, p(z, x), since we as the model builders specify p(z) as well as p(x|z). E.g. p(z) is a 2 variate normal with specified mean/cov, and p(x|z) is a normal with mean z[0] and var z[1]. We can just plug in the prior into the likelihood to get its full functional form, and then multiply by the prior to get the full functional form of the joint. Right?

Comment: Can you explicitly write out the form of the density for $p(x,z)$?

Comment: We have $z0, z1 \sim N(\mathbf{\mu}, \mathbf{\Sigma})$. First, sample a particular pair from this, call it $z0_i, z1_i$. Then $p(x_i, z_i)$ (where $z_i = \begin{bmatrix} z0_i \\ z1_i\end{bmatrix}$) can be written as $p(z_i) * p(x_i | z_i) = c_1*exp\left( -.5(z_i-\mu)^\top \Sigma^{-1}(z_i-\mu)\right) * c_2 *e^{\frac{-(x_i-z0_i)^2}{2z1_i^2}}$. I just wrote the normalizing constants as $c_1$ and $c_2$ but hopefully its clear what I mean. We have access to mu and sigma (we specify the prior on z) and can sample a $z_i$ vector, and have access to $x_i$ (we have data afterall). Is this right?

Comment: If this is your model, then is seems like you’re not parameterizing a neural network — the usual VAE usage

Comment: Ah I see, so VI and the ELBO are only relevant for more complex models, involving things like neural nets?

Comment: Yeah, your core observation is correct — you only need an approximation when the thing you’re computing is intractable. But if you can be exact for little/no cost, then go for it!

Comment: Sorry for the late follow up, but can you elaborate on intractability? Let's go with the example of a VAE which I'm familiar with and its a common example of VI. What exactly is the intractable part of the joint? In principle when you instantiate the encoder and decoder, they have parameters so they can compute things (namely a latent distribution and data distribution respectively). Where does intractability fit in?

Comment: The normal distribution model you've proposed here seems to be the one you're most familiar with & it is not intractable. The intractable problems arise from the latent variables $z$ and model parameters $\theta$, which do not have simple conjugate form in a convolutional neural network. I recommend reading Carl Doersch, "Tutorial on Variational Autoencoders"
and the original VAE papers for more detail.

Answer (score 4):

As you stated, we have:
$$
KL(q(z) || p(z|x)) = \mathbb{E}_{z \sim q} \left[ \log \frac{q(z)}{p(z,x)}\right] + \log p(x),
$$
where $-\mathbb{E}_{z \sim q} \left[ \log \frac{q(z)}{p(z,x)}\right]$ is also called the ELBO. And the goal is to minimize $KL(q(z) || p(z|x))$. And you are right, since the log evidence is constant, minimizing the RHS means maximizing the ELBO, which in turn means approximating $p(x, z)$ with $q(z)$.

But note that, although we do know the functional form of the joint $p(x, z) = p_\theta(x, z)$, we usually don't know the value for its parameter $\theta$. The same goes for $q(z)$: the functional form for $q(z) = q_\phi(z)$ is usually known (because it is chosen to be simple), but the parameter $\phi$ is not known. So the task is to find the parameters $\theta$ and $\phi$ by maximizing the ELBO.

E.g., think of some state space model, where you want to use variational inference to obtain the posterior of the state space $z$ given the observations $x$. You know that the state space model is defined by some parameters $\theta$ but those are not known to you. Next, you presume some function $q_\phi(z|x)$ that should approximate $p_\theta(z|x)$. This $q_\phi$, too, depends on some yet unknown parameters $\phi$ that need to be inferred (otherwise there would be nothing left to do since you then already know your approximation $q$). Another popular example would be the VAE where the parameters of the densities $p_\theta(x|z)$ and $q_\phi(z|x)$ like e.g. mean and covariance, are given by (deep) neural networks of prescribed architecture and the parameters $\theta$ and $\phi$ are the weights of the neural networks that need to be learned.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response! Regarding your first point: Why exactly does it not mean we are approximating p(x, z) with q? We want to minimize the RHS, we don't have access to the evidence so we simply minimize the expectation term, which by definition, is the KL between the variational and joint. Isn't our final step to minimize KL between q and the joint? Doesn't this mean we apx the joint with q? Regarding the second point: What models would you not have access to the functional form? I'm thimking of an HMM, we specify p(z) and the likelihood, can't we multiply and have the joint?

Comment: @Addison I edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update @frank, I'm a bit confused on how we wouldn't have access to the parameter $\theta$. If we have access to the functional form of the joint, this means we can write it as a formula e.g. if p(z) is N(0, 1) and p(x|z) is N(z, 1), then $p(x,z) = N(0, 1) * N(z, 1)$ right? Is the issue that we have to sample from the prior to get a $z$ which then dictates the likelihood? Or maybe I'm missing the point somehow or am not 100% certain on whats meant by the parameters of the joint here

Comment: @Addison Again, I added more information to the answer.